# LLVM exception throwing

Tags: exception, llvm

I have read [this blog post](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/11/llvm-30-exception-handling-redesign.html), [this documentation page](http://www.llvm.org/docs/ExceptionHandling.html) and [this example](https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk/examples/ExceptionDemo/ExceptionDemo.cpp), but I still don't understand how to throw a basic exception using the LLVM's IRBuilder for a non-C++ oriented language.

From my understanding, I have to :

- Create a `llvm::Value` containing the throwed value.
- Call *"a function"*, passing it the throwed value. This function will not return.

The example is using a system rewinding function (`_Unwind_RaiseException`) in order to throw a C++ exception, and I don't really understand how to use my own raising function instead (since I only need to throw an object pointer). What am I missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is that `_Unwind_RaiseException` is not a C++-specific function. It comes from the libunwind library, and allows to throw any type of exception.

More details can be found on [these blog posts](http://monoinfinito.wordpress.com/category/programming/c/exceptions/page/3/).

Answer (score 0):

As you don't want to use existing C++ exception handling infrastructure, you'll need to replicate parts of it for your language.

You can use the implementation of C unwinder in [compiler-rt](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/compiler-rt/blob/master/lib/gcc_personality_v0.c) (or significantly more complex one in [libstdc++](http://code.google.com/codesearch#Yj7Hz1ZInUg/trunk/gcc-4.2.1/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/eh_personality.cc)), and invocation of an unwinder in [libstdc++](http://code.google.com/codesearch#Yj7Hz1ZInUg/trunk/gcc-4.2.1/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/eh_throw.cc&ct=rc&cd=1&q=__cxa_throw) to start with.

Comment: All those links are now dead…